# injective holomorphic mapping between unit disk and unit polydisk

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

In $\mathbb{C}^n,\ n\geq 2$, there is no bijection between unit disk $B^n(0,1)$ and unit polydisk $P^n(0,1)$. But if we wish to find injective holomorphic mapping from unit disk to polydisk(whose image contains origin), inclusion is the obvious mapping or suitable automorphisms of unit disk(which is sort of inclusion, after applying automorphism). But can we go beyond unit disk in polydisk, by means of injective holomorphic mapping. Are there results in this direction available?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is - to find an injective map from the unit ball to the polydisk with the image not in the unit ball? You can map $B^n(0,1)$ to some small in the "corner" of the polydisk.

Comment: I want to see, if we can find a map, whose image contains origin, but also consists points out of $B^n(0,1)$. Edited my question a bit.

Comment: How about $z\mapsto 2z$?

Comment: @Henri Its image not be within polydisk $P^n(0,1)$

Comment: Ok, I hadn't seen that you wanted the image to be contained in the polydisk.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, given a point in $x\in P^n(0,1)- B^n(0,1)$ you are asking if there is an injective map $f:B^n(0,1)\rightarrow P^n(0,1)$ such that $f(B^n(0,1))$ contains $0$ and $x$?  If so then (think for simplicity $n=2$) take $\epsilon>0$ very small and $r=|x|+\epsilon$ such that the image of the unit ball under the map $(z,w)\rightarrow (r z,\epsilon w)$ is almost a flat disk then use a unitary tranformation $A\in U(2)$ to rotate this thickened disk in direction of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(z_1,z_2):=(z_1,sz_2+(1-s)z_1)$, $0<s<1$. For example, $s=1/2$. Then $f$ is an injective holomorphic mapping from $B(0,1)$ to $P(0,1)$, ($n=2$), sending $0$ to $0$. Moreover, $\|f(s,0)\|>1$ for $s<1$, near $1$, i.e. $f(s,0)\notin B(0,1)$..